# Entity Framework Core 2.0.0 Migrations in different project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two projects.

1) .NetCore Console App

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0

I have a an entry point

```
class Program
{
    private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();

        Configuration = configurationRoot;

        // create service collection
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        // create service provider
        serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    }
}
```

and an appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "****"
  }
}
```

2) .NetStandard Lib (contains DbContext)

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0

I want to be able to create a migration script using `dotnet ef migrations add [NAME]` and i've worked out if I run the command whilst in the lib folder I can target a startup project to run the migrations.

`D:\Lib> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s ..\ConsoleApp\`

I managed to get this working by adding a class in the same folder as MyDbContext that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` I can add a connection string and it runs perfectly.

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("****", optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

> The problem I have is I want to use the connection string from within
>   the console app's appsettings.json.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I have a solution, though i'm not sure if i'm happy with it.

My program.cs is now:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

I moved the class implementing `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` from the project with MyDbContext to the console application and it now looks like:

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();

        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

so the console app is:

- program.cs
- MyDbContextFactory.cs

The command i'm running is still

`D:\Lib> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s ..\ConsoleApp\`

I couldn't remove the reference on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer as the migration scripts were saved to the lib project and had references to the library.  If I had the migration scripts going to a different folder that would mean I could remove the dependency, but i'm ok with that for now.